# Will avoiding "bundling and minification" in lieu of serving .js and .css from Azure blob be beneficial?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-blob-storage

We have an MVC web site deployed in a Cloud Service on Microsoft Azure. For boosting performance, some of my colleagues suggested that we avoid the bundling and minification provided by ASP.NET MVC4 and instead store the .js and .css files on an Azure blob. Please note that the solution does not use a CDN, it merely serves the files from a blob.

My take on this is that just serving the files this way will not cause any major performance benefits. Since we are not using a CDN, the files will get served from the region in which our storage is deployed all the time. Ever time a user requests a page, at least for the first time, the data will flow across the data center boundary and that will in turn incur cost. Also, since they are not bundled but kept as individual files, the server requests will be more. So we are forfeiting the benefits of bundling and minification. The only benefit I see to this approach is that we can do changes to the .js and .css files and upload them without a need to re-deploy.

Can anyone please tell me which of the two options is preferable in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see how this would be better than bundling and minification unless the intent is to blob store your minified and bundled files. The whole idea is to reduce requests to the server because javascript processes a single thread at a time and in addition there's added download time, I'd do everything I can to reduce that request count.

As a separate note on the image side, I'd also combine images into a single image and use css sprites ala: http://vswebessentials.com/features/bundling

Comment: Exactly my take on it. Unless we use a CDN so that the requests are served via the CDN instead of hitting the server, storing in the blobs will actually forfeit the benefits of bundling and also have an overhead of accessing resources from the blob instead of from the package itself. As for the images, we have used the sprite approach. css sprites is something I should look at. Thanks for your input.